# Why The Empty Rows aren't getting Deleted (Pandas Dataframe)?

Tags: python, pandas

> EDIT : Sorry, I got confused rows with Columns,(noob here)

> I have a CSV , where there are 3 columns, `heading, image and description` .

> Some of the items in description is Empty , and I want to delete the complete column if description is empty or has `length < 1`

> Firstly, I got all columns which has length of `description < 1` using this Code :

```
for i in df['description']:
if len(i) < 1 :
    print('Empty')
```

> **Output :**

```
Empty
Empty
```

> This means there are 2 columns which has description of length < 1 , Now i try to remove them :

```
for i in df['description']:
if len(i) < 1 :
    df.drop(i, inplace=True, axis=1)
```

> But, still there are those 2 columns with Empty data, how to remove them, What is wrong in my code ? Please Guide

> also tried :

```
df = df.drop(df.columns[[i]], axis=1)
```

> but, nothing works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a little of confusion.
You say you want to remove the entire column, but this means deleting the `description` column; instead, I think you're talking about the row with empty description.

If this is your case, then you just need to cycle over your dataframe (with an index too) and check if the `description` is null or empty; if that's true, you can drop the row in-place (`index=N` means `i, axis=0`).

```
for i, description in zip(df.index, df['description']):
    if not description:  # True if None and empty string
        df.drop(index=i, inplace=True)
```

This is an example of what you're getting.

```
before drop:
  heading image description
0     foo     a        None
1     bar     b            
2     baz     c   some text

after drop:
  heading image description
2     baz     c   some text
```

If, however, you need to remove the entire column if there is a None/empty string, then you need to check first if there are values that match your search, and if yes, remove that column.

`df.applymap()` applies a function to all DataFrame, then you keep only the `description` column, and you got a bool Series. With `any()` you check if at least one element is True (None or empty string). If yes, drop all the `description` column.

```
if any(df.applymap(lambda x: not x)['description']):
    df.drop(columns='description', inplace=True)
```

Again, here's an example of result.

```
before drop:
  heading image description
0     foo     a        None
1     bar     b            
2     baz     c   some text

after drop:
  heading image
0     foo     a
1     bar     b
2     baz     c
```

Comment: Sorry, I got confused rows with Columns,(noob here)  . I wanted to delete the row and not column

Comment: Following Your Code , I tried this : for i in df['description']:
    if len(i) < 1 :
        df.drop(index=i, inplace=True)     , still it has the items. not deleted

Comment: I gave you the right answer with an example of result. By the way, you're not cycling over index (`i`), but over values (`None`, `''`, `'some text'`, etc)

Comment: How to write correct One Sir, please Guide

Comment: Just check the first code block in my answer, that's the correct `for` loop